# Auto selection of Text in TextInput and BackSpace problem in KIVY

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

My code is works fine on PC but when converted into APK file i get problem with the use of Auto selection of text in TextInput and backspace on Android

As simple my problem  in Android APK is that
" When i starting  to type "**Hello**" and after completing a word i uses space bar then the following text is ADDED to the  the TextInput field and changes to "**HelloHello**", as well correct to edit  back the that word uses BackSpace which is not worked  very well.

I never have this on the PC, but always on Android.

As i am using KIVY version 2.0.0  and MDKIVY version 0.104.2
and my Buildozer spec file in the following.

```
 [app]

 # (str) Title of your application
 title = My Application

 # (str) Package name
 package.name = myapp

 # (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
 package.domain = org.test

 # (str) Source code where the main.py live
 source.dir = .

 # (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
 source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

 # (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
 #source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

 # (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
 #source.exclude_exts = spec

 # (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
 #source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

  # (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
 #source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

 # (str) Application versioning (method 1)
 version = 0.1

 # (str) Application versioning (method 2)
 # version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
 # version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

 # (list) Application requirements
 # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
 requirements = = python3,kivy==master,kivymd,requests,urllib3,pillow

 # (str) Custom source folders for requirements
 # Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
 # requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

 # (list) Garden requirements
 #garden_requirements =

 # (str) Presplash of the application
 #presplash.filename = image.jpg

 # (str) Icon of the application
 #icon.filename = image.jpg

 # (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
 orientation = portrait

 # (list) List of service to declare
 #services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

 #
 # OSX Specific
 #

 #
 # author = © Copyright Info

 # change the major version of python used by the app
 osx.python_version = 3

 # Kivy version to use
 osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

 #
 # Android specific
 #

 # (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
 fullscreen = 1

  # (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
  # Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
  # red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
  # darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
  # olive, purple, silver, teal.
  android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

  # (list) Permissions
  android.permissions = INTERNET

  # (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
  android.api = 27

  # (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
  android.minapi = 21

  # (int) Android SDK version to use
  android.sdk = 20

  # (str) Android NDK version to use
  android.ndk = 19b

  # (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it 
     should usually match android.minapi.
  android.ndk_api = 21

   # (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
   #android.private_storage = True

   # (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
   #android.ndk_path =

  # (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
   #android.sdk_path =

    # (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
    #android.ant_path =

    # (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
    # This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
   # when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
   android.skip_update = False

    # (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
    # agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
    # the default, you will be shown the license when first running
    # buildozer.
    android.accept_sdk_license = True

    # (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
    #android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

    # (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
    # android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

    # (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
    #android.whitelist =

    # (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
    #android.whitelist_src =

    # (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
    #android.blacklist_src =

    # (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
    # their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
    # down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
     # OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
    #android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

    # (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
    # directory containing the files)
     #android.add_src =

    # (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
    # bootstrap)
    #android.add_aars =

     # (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
     # bootstrap)
     #android.gradle_dependencies =

     # (list) add java compile options
     # this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using 
       the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
      # see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further   
      information
       # android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

       # (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
      # please enclose in double quotes 
      # e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
      #android.add_gradle_repositories =

      # (list) packaging options to add 
       # see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
        # can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
       # please enclose in double quotes 
       # e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
        #android.add_gradle_repositories =

         # (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
        #android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

         # (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
         # If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
         #android.ouya.category = GAME

         # (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
         #android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

         # (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
         #android.manifest.intent_filters =

         # (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
         #android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

          # (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
          #android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
          #android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
          #android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
          #android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
           #android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

          # (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
          # Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
           #android.wakelock = False

          # (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
          #android.meta_data =

           # (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
           # project.properties automatically.)
          #android.library_references =

           # (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
           #android.uses_library =

            # (str) Android logcat filters to use
            #android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

            # (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
            #android.copy_libs = 1

            # (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
            android.arch = armeabi-v7a

            # (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
             # this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
             # android.numeric_version = 1

              #
               # Python for android (p4a) specific
             #

              # (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
             #p4a.fork = kivy

             # (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
             p4a.branch = develop

             # (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
             #p4a.source_dir = p4a

             # (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
             #p4a.local_recipes =

             # (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
             #p4a.hook =

             # (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
             #p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

             # (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
             #p4a.port =


             #
             # iOS specific
             #

             # (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
             #ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
              # Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
             ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
             ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

              # Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
              # Uncomment to use a custom checkout
              #ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
              # Or specify URL and branch
              ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
              ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

              # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
              # Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
               #ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

               # (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
              #ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


              [buildozer]

               # (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
               log_level = 2

               # (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
                warn_on_root = 1

                # (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
                build_dir = ./.buildozer

                # (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
                 bin_dir = ./bin

                #    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                #    List as sections
                #
                 #    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
                 #    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
                 #    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
                 #    Instead of doing:
                 #
                 #[app]
                 #source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
                 #
                 #    This can be translated into:
                 #
                  #[app:source.exclude_patterns]
                  #license
                  #data/audio/*.wav
                  #data/images/original/*
                  #


                 #                 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  #    Profiles
                    #
                  #    You can extend section / key with a profile
                 #    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
                  #    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
                 #    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
                #
                 #[app@demo]
                 #title = My Application (demo)
                 #
                #[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
                #images/hd/*
                #
                #    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
                #
                #buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Partially i have go trough the github following link https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/issues/2461 , in this person facing same problem as I and there is small video which is exactly matches with my problem,  but i don't understand the solution of that.

Thank You so much.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This problem occured to me when I changed android-version. Up to version 7.1.1. TextInput worked fine ...